# StartActivity crashes with RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, exception, android-activity

I'm trying to start new activity by button click.

Main Activity code:

```
public class HelloScreenActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button btn_lang = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_lang_rus);
        btn_lang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("type", getString(R.string.routes));
                    intent.setClass(HelloScreenActivity.this, RoutesListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);  
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    ShowMessage(exc.getMessage());  
                }               
            }
        });

}
```

Next activity code:

```
    public class RoutesListActivity extends Activity{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.routes_list);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        String type = (String) extras.get("type");

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ent_list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(null, 0);
        final String[] routes = {this.getString(R.string.greenline), this.getString(R.string.redline)};
        if(type == "Routes")
        {      
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, routes);
            list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int pos,
                    long id) {
                try
                {       
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("display", routes[pos]);
                    intent.setClass(RoutesListActivity.this, TheMapActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);  
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    ShowMessage(exc.getMessage());  
                }               
            }
        });
    }

    }
```

When I press a button, app crashes (on `startActivity(intent)` call)

Stack trace:

```
02-26 19:39:35.382: W/dalvikvm(19398): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thumbsupstudio.mobitour/com.thumbsupstudio.mobitour.RoutesListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:230)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1920)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1969)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:314)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:228)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:605)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:164)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:160)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:156)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at com.thumbsupstudio.mobitour.RoutesListActivity.onCreate(RoutesListActivity.java:18)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
02-26 19:39:35.493: E/AndroidRuntime(19398):    ... 11 more
```

**UPDATE**

The problem was in `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(null, 0);`

How to init ArrayAdapter correctly?

Comment: Have you noticed this line in the logcat: `at com.thumbsupstudio.mobitour.RoutesListActivity.onCreate(RoutesListActivity.java:18)`? I think the problem is in your RoutesListActivity, but it seems that you didn't paste the full codes.

Comment: Right. I added full code of RoutesListActivity

Comment: why are you write like,,.  ListView list = new ListView(null);

Comment: I corrected it, it remainded from some manipulations.. doesn't matter and doesn't influence on the code, error continue to occur

Comment: Can you add the most recent code, update the stack trace if needed and tell us which line is 18 of your `RoutesListActivity` class.

Comment: just double click that line in the logcat to locate the sentence that results in the problem. Another, ` if(type == "Routes")` looks very questionable, since you won't use "==" operator to compare two strings in general.

Comment: it's all right with "==", the problem was in `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(null, 0);` . How to init ArrayAdapter correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to initialize `ArrayAdapter` with null context in line

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(null, 0);
```

Pass `RoutesListActivity.this` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have u registerd your `RoutesListActivity` In the `AndroidManifest.xml`? If not then add these lines in the manifest file

```
    <activity android:name=".RoutesListActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the NullPointerException comes from the `if(type == "Routes")` sentence. When you want to check if the contents from two strings are the same, you should use `StringA.equals(StringB)`, rather than `StringA==StringB`.

So `type == "Routes"` will always return you `false`, and thus the listview has not been instantiated correctly, and `arrayAdapter` becomes NULL. That's why you get the NullPointerException.

Comment: I changed it, but it seems that the error wasn't in it. Look an update in my post, I found an issue location

Comment: Why not just declare that variable? You really instantiated it in your `if(type == "Routes")` code block. I understand that you want to show different list depending on the value of type.

Comment: You mean to instantiate to `ArrayAdapter` some value and change it again after comparison?

Comment: Yes.this is a solution.  I actually mean to declare it, but not set the value.after the comparison, set the right value.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

Try something like :

```
public class RoutesListActivity extends Activity{
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{ 
    String type= getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("type").toString();
    }catch (Exception e) { Log.e("this is why ..."); }
...
```

Comment: The error occurs later, in line 18. I posted this line in my post(update)